# Show that x is primal feasible

Tags: linear-programming

I have one exercise asking me to show that $x*=(3/2,1)$ is primal feasible for the linear programming problem:
$$max 3x_1 +2x_2$$
$$2x_1+x_2 \leq 4$$
$$2x_1+3x_2 \leq 6$$
I can see that it fulfill the constraints. But is there any other method to show so? And also is it optimal solution?

EDIT:

The question now is: Is $x^*$ optimal?

Comment: Hint: Where there's a primal, there's a dual.

Comment: yeah I know, the dual feasible is y=(5/4,1/4)..

Comment: Also help :))))

Answer (score 0):

As this is an LP in two variables, you can plot the feasible region and check if this lies in the region. For optimality, we know that optimal solutions to convex LPs lie on the boundary, so if this point lies on one of the two lines (generally, hyperplanes), you can almost be sure you have an optimal solution.

Comment: Is there any mathmatical way to find it out? I've tried that :)

Comment: Not really. Really, feasibility just asks if a point satisfies all constraints. Nothing complicated about that.